# Highcharts generated from HTML table: Can't add second yAxis dynamically

Tags: highcharts, datatables

I have a variable column HTML table (in this example one date column, and three value columns). Generating a Highchart from this is simple by using the datatable as the charts' input data:

```
this.chart = Highcharts.chart(this.container.nativeElement, {
     data: {table: 'datatable'},
    ...
}
```

where I only get one yAxis, based on the last value column. This is probably as expected.

The issue: I'd like there to be a separate yAxis for each of the three value columns, with the table column header name as the yAxis label/name. Please see the screenshot below.

[image: Datatable and Highcharts]

In the above screenshot you can see that the three series have different ranges, and the one with the lowest values ("Value1") is basically displayed as being flat.

Using the `Highcharts.Chart.addAxis()` function works somewhat - I get the new yAxis label, but no mapping from the corresponding value column with gridlines. 
The challenge is that everything is loaded dynamically. Beforehand I don't know how many columns I will get, and correspondingly I don't know how many yAxis' I have to display.

All examples I've seen use hardcoded yAxis information and are of no help. I'm running out of possible Stack Overflow answers, and so far I unfortunately haven't found any addressing this particular issue.

Comment: Could you share a [MCVE] for your current solution, preferably in the form of a jsfiddle or similar? That would make it a lot easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to adding an axis, you must also connect it to the appropriate series:

```
chart.addAxis({
    opposite: true
});

chart.series[1].update({
    yAxis: 1
});
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1bkvcwmp/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update